# PIVOT by timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to pivot the time (hour) for the results of this query, so there could be up to 24 hours running across the top as you can replicate in an Excel pivot table. Is there an easy and efficient way to replicate this in the query?

Query:

```
SELECT
  trunc(complete_dstamp) "Date", 
  to_char(complete_dstamp, 'HH24') "Hour", 
  user_id "User", 
  sum(update_qty) "Qty" 
FROM
  inventory_transaction 
WHERE
  to_loc_id = 'CONTAINER' 
  and trunc(complete_dstamp) > (
    trunc(current_timestamp)-1
  ) 
GROUP BY
  trunc(complete_dstamp), 
  to_char(complete_dstamp, 'HH24'), 
  user_id 
ORDER BY
  1, 
  2
```

Desired output:

[image: Excel pivot]

Current output:

[image: query results]

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Date",
       user_id AS "User",
       SUM(CASE TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'HH24') WHEN '00' THEN update_qty END) AS hour_0,
       SUM(CASE TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'HH24') WHEN '01' THEN update_qty END) AS hour_1,
       SUM(CASE TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'HH24') WHEN '02' THEN update_qty END) AS hour_2,
       SUM(CASE TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'HH24') WHEN '03' THEN update_qty END) AS hour_3,
       SUM(CASE TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'HH24') WHEN '04' THEN update_qty END) AS hour_4,
       -- ...
       SUM(CASE TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'HH24') WHEN '23' THEN update_qty END) AS hour_23,
       sum(update_qty) AS grand_total
FROM   inventory_transaction
WHERE  to_loc_id = 'CONTAINER'
AND    complete_dstamp >= trunc(current_timestamp)
GROUP BY
       TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
       user_id
ORDER BY
       "Date",
       "User"
```

Or a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT "Date",
       user_id AS "User",
       hour_0,
       hour_1,
       hour_2,
       hour_3,
       hour_4,
       -- ...
       hour_23,
       COALESCE(hour_0, 0)
       + COALESCE(hour_1, 0)
       + COALESCE(hour_2, 0)
       + COALESCE(hour_3, 0)
       + COALESCE(hour_4, 0)
       -- ...
       + COALESCE(hour_23, 0) AS grand_total
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Date",
         TO_CHAR(complete_dstamp, 'HH24') AS hour,
         user_id,
         update_qty
  FROM   inventory_transaction
  WHERE  to_loc_id = 'CONTAINER'
  AND    complete_dstamp >= trunc(current_timestamp)
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(update_qty) FOR hour IN (
     '00' AS hour_0,
     '01' AS hour_1,
     '02' AS hour_2,
     '03' AS hour_3,
     '04' AS hour_4,
    -- ...
    '23' AS hour_23
  )
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c88ae5334d85e891c2532445faf2980)*

Comment: Perfect, thanks MTO